# Different style in same browser

Tags: css, browser, cross-browser

I made a website where you find a div with some text placed in it.

I am using the exact same FireFox version as my client, however, the text stands out of the box a bit for her while it looks perfect here.

How can that be? We use the exact same version of Firefox!

Comment: Post your code, an example, something...

Answer (score 3):

Theories:

- her browser zoom is set to a different default than yours
- her font size is set to a different default than yours
- she has different fonts installed than yours
- she has a different OS and/or different OS type rendering default settings

Odds are you are using fixed size elements and/or absolute positioning and aren't taking into consideration the wide variations in type rendering and user preferences. Make sure your text elements are contained and are able to expand as needed.